# How to Render Raw a HTML Image in React That is Stored Locally on a Server?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to display a raw HTML webpage with an image that is stored locally on server in my network.

```
    module.exports = `
<html>

<img src="file://thisLocalServer/image.jpg" />

</html>`
```

When I try to display this image however, it displays the default blank placeholder image.
This is my App.js file.

```
var __html = require('./html.test.js');
var template = { __html: __html}

    render() {
        return(
            <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={template}/>
        );
```

If I try setting the image source as a normal link like `https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png` then it appears to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this download the image, put it in the folder with the `index.html` or a subfolder with the `index.html` and put the following link:

`<img src="foldername/image-name.format">`

Or via javascript:

```
document.location.pathname + '/foldername/image-name.format';
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, with the code above, no image will ever be shown.

Details:

There are several issues with the `src` attribute of the `<img>` tag.

- 1st, the `src` is not recommended to use `file://` protocol
- 2nd, it looks like you are missing a slash, it could be `file:///filesystem/path/to/img.jpg`

But in my exp, even you fix the 2nd one, your image will not load because of the 1st one. This is a security reach if the access to a webpage (through `http` or `https` protocol) is able to know the filesystem of the server.